# Where to put Logback JNDI for Jboss webapp?

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, logback, jndi, slf4j

For a jboss .war application I received instructions to configure its SLF4j/Logback, setting a folder path string with java:/comp/env/xyz JNDI variable.
I'm using Jboss EAP 7, do I need to set it somewhere in the standalone.xml file? What syntax should be used? The official Logback docs don't help me with Jboss.

EDIT:
More info, the actual code looks for the resource in this way:

```
basepath = (String) initialContext.lookup("java:/comp/env/" + MyBasePath);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself, the variable can be set in standalone.xml here:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">
            <bindings>
                <simple name="java:/comp/env/xyz" value="<PATH>" type="java.lang.String"/>
            </bindings>
            <remote-naming/>
</subsystem>
```